# SignInWithEmailAndPassword no funciona

Tags: firebase, xamarin

Estoy programando el login de una app, para la autenticacion uso firebaseAuth, pero el metodo **SignInWithEmailAndPassword()** le pase los datos que le pase, siempre se termina, no sé como hacer para que cuando meta un usuario que no está en la base de datos salte la excepción o devuelva false, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar!

```
public bool SignIn(string email, string password)
    {  
        try
        {
                FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(MainActivity.app).SignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber si firebase tiene el email del usuario que se esta tratando de registrar puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {                           
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                           //se registro el usuario correctamente
                        }else{
                            Log.i("Respuesta","Fallo al crear el usuario:"+task.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

La excepcion `task.getException().getMessage();` te va a devolver esto si el email existe para ese usuario

**"Respuesta: The email address is already in use by another account."**